# Need assistance with strange progressive numbering on file extension

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-explorer, file-extension

In this image:

[image: Screenshot of Get-Childitem output]

you can see that I was using Powershell to count the number of files by type, however, I noticed something unusual in the counts. That is, there are file extensions with progressive numbering, like `*.package(1)` and `*.package(2)` for example.

What I don't understand and need help with is, even though PS shows these files existing, when I go into the searched folders, and sort by type, Windows Explorer apparently can't tell the difference between a `*.package` and a `*.package(1)` or further on. and as you can see, I have a lot of packages, so trying to individually look at each and every file extension line by line, would be impossible, at least for me. I don't mean that in a 'lazy' way or anything, I have impaired vision, so looking at things 'line by line' is simply not possible.

So, I took to Google, but I either do not know how to phrase my search requests, or the answer simply doesn't exist, because I have found no solutions to locating these files.

Thus, my question here, is there a way to use either Windows Command Shell or Powershell to locate the files that have (#) at the end of the extension type, and move them to another folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Explorer**, you can add the `File extension` column and group on that --- that may do the trick.

In **PowerShell**:

```
$Source = 'C:\Path\to\files'
$Dest   = 'C:\Destination\Folder'
Get-ChildItem $Source -File -Recurse |  Where Extension -match '\(.+\)' | Move-Item -Destination $Dest
```

- Note that the `-File` parameter elliminates the need for `Where {-not $_.PSIsContainer }`
- [`-Match operator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-match-and--notmatch)